# How to lock the desktop using visual basic and connect the computers in lan?

Tags: lan

How to make a screen locker in visual basic such that whole desktop gets locked and a login screen appears on screen to unlock via password only.as the client enters correct password and clicks on login screen button,he can access the desktop and his login time gets stored in server's database. And an idea of server client connection in visual basic.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare a procedure like this

```
Private Declare Sub LockWorkStation Lib "user32.dll" ()
```

and then you will call it by

```
LockWorkStation()
```

Good luck with that :)